# Failing to upload a publicly available file on S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am attempting to upload a publicly available file on S3 using Boto3 but I am getting the following error message:

```
boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload 1.txt to my-texts/1.txt: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

This is my policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-texts"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-texts/*"
    }
]
```

}

This is the code that fails:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                             aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                             aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
                             aws_session_token=aws_session_token,
                             region_name='us-east-1')
s3_client.upload_file(video_file_name, bucket_name, video_file_name, ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'})
```

If I omit the ExtraArgs I succeed uploading the file:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                             aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                             aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
                             aws_session_token=aws_session_token,
                             region_name='us-east-1')
s3_client.upload_file(video_file_name, bucket_name, video_file_name)
```

Thanks, Pavel

Comment: What permissions are associated with the credentials you are using to make the upload? They appear to be coming from a Security Token Service call, such as AssumeRole. Is that correct?

Comment: Based on your testing results, you might need to also grant `s3:PutObjectAcl` permission.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Tried that as well.. Still doesn't work

Comment: Looking at the request in **AWS CloudTrail** _might_ yield some more information. Specifically, look at the difference between the two requests and see whether multiple API calls are being made (aside from the `PutObject` request).

Comment: Tried to add a trail on AWS but getting an "An internal error occurred. Please refresh the page and retry" error :/
Will try to talk to their tech support I guess. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein This was the correct solution, it turns I had another problem there with finding a file that wasn't about the S3 upload. Thanks!